# Hide UINavigationBarController in first view controller and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a design for an app with 3 screens where the

- A) initial screen shall not show top navigation bar
- B) second screen shall show top navigation bar (with a nav back button to A)
- C) third screen shall not show top navigation bar (but a normal button back to B)

I chose to embed the view controllers in a navigation bar.
But doing so the AutoLayout constraints on the first view controller poops out plenty of warnings - because the embedded UIViews are pinned to the top bar - which is really annoying.

Of course if I "hide" the navigation bar in the storyboard designer, I am no longer able to add the required buttons for by B screen.

An alternate option COULD be to implement the navigational properties of my app all manually, but I really want to avoid doing this.

What is the preferred (best practice) solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Its Too simple...
you just set hidden attribute of navigation controller in **viewWillAppear** ex:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES/NO; //as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. sorry I wasn't too clear in my question. That still doesn't get rid of my AutoLayout issues shown in the designer. I've chosen not to use the navigation controller for now. Too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in @SonuPatel answer, you can set the navigation bar to hidden relatively easily. For layout:

In controllers A and C, make your top layout offsets relative to the view and not the top layout guide. This will make them layout under the navigation bar when it is not visible. Hidden items usually still contribute to layout, so the topLayout guide is unaffected by it being hidden.

In controller B, make your top layout relative to the top layout guide to keep it below the navigation bar.

For a UITableViewController, you can get this for free by selecting Extend Edges Under Top Bars in the attribute inspector.